# Exception raised after loading pickle file: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to load a pickle file that contains a dictionary:

```
import pickle as pk

# load dMAD
dMAD_open = open(r"dMAD.pickle", "rb")
dMAD = pk.load(dMAD_open)
dMAD_open.close()

type(dMAD) # prints correctly: "dict"
dMAD # throws the error message
```

The loading works without raising an error, but once I try to print dMAD (which should retrun the dictionary) I get this error message:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'

I already tried different conda environments with different python installations (python 3.7.7 and 3.8.2).
The pickle file and my code are in the same directory.
It works on a different computer. It doesn't work on mine, even when I use the same conda environment.

How can I solve this issue? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the full code ? It looks like the error appears on a line not shown here. The reference to DataFrame indicates maybe you'Re using pandas ?

Comment: This is all the code that I am running. It is possible that the code that dumps the pickle file is using pandas, but I don't know that, because I don't have access to that, I only get the pickle file. But even if I import pandas, the error message remains the same.

Comment: I found this that may be of help. It appears there might be a pandas version issue between the pickled datagrams and your environment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559007/unpickling-dictionary-that-holds-pandas-dataframes-throws-attributeerror-dataf

Comment: Apparently can't edit my comment now but I meant to say dataframes, obviously. Autocorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, it worked in an environment running python 3.8.5 and pandas 1.1.3

Answer (score 1):

You might want to catch the exception manually like:

```
try:
    open(r"dMAD.pickle", "rb")
catch Exception as e:
    print(e) # you will find what is going on here
```

or even have a deeper look on what is inside this dict with

```
dir(dMAD)
```

If you believe it is environment error, go ahead and reinstall it again from the scratch and most probably this is the case.
keep on mind if you recently upgraded python version on your local machine that corrupts all old virtual environments if not kept the old version available in the same path.

#### try to remove the old environment and install a fresh one.