# Save a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I have generated myself like:

[image: Dataframe]

I would want to save it using pickle (the only way I know to do that) using:

```
df.to_pickle(file_name)
```

To use it then with:

```
df = pd.read_pickle(file_name)
```

The problem is that using this I'm getting a file that the other program don't know how to read:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("dataframe.pkl")
print(df)
```

I'm getting an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What versions of Python and pandas are you using? Was the pickle created with the same versions of both?

Comment: I'm using the 2.0 version of pickle, the 3.7.3 of python and 1.1.4 of pandas. Ara all versions compatible? Thanks! @BallpointBen

Comment: I'd check that the pickle was created with the same version of pandas. If it was, try downgrading pandas to 1.1.0. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559007/unpickling-dictionary-that-holds-pandas-dataframes-throws-attributeerror-dataf